# I want to get doc data from Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

```
/* eslint-disable indent */
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {
  Alert,
} from 'react-native';
import firebase from 'firebase';
// import { useIsFocused } from '@react-navigation/native';
import Chart from '../components/Chart';
import LogoutButton from '../components/LogoutButton';

export default function Main(props) {
  // const isFocused = useIsFocused();
  const { navigation } = props;
  useEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      headerRight: () => <LogoutButton />,
  });
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => {
    const currentUser = firebase.auth();
    const db = firebase.firestore();
    let unsubscribe = () => {};
    if (currentUser) {
      const ref = db.collection(`users/${currentUser.uid}/memos`).orderBy('updatedAt', 'desc');
      unsubscribe = ref.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          console.log(doc.id, doc.data());
          });
      }, (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
    }
      return unsubscribe;
    }, []);

    return (
      <Chart />
        );
    }
```

```
doc.id, doc.data()
```

↑I want to get these infomation but nothing is displayed on console despite writting `console.log(doc.id, doc.data());`
`console.log(error);`　thought...

```
snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
```

↑I put `console.log('abc')` before `snapshot.forEach((doc) => {`
abc was displayed on console so I think `snapshot.forEach((doc) => {` causes something wrong.
However, I have no idea what's wrong with this so I need help to solve this issue.

After changing **Dear Bargros**

```
`useEffect(() => {
    const currentUser = firebase.auth();
    const db = firebase.firestore();
   async function asyncCall() {
    const ref = await db.collection('users/${currentUser.uid}/memos').orderBy('updatedAt', 'desc').get(),
    then
    const docs = ref.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
    console.log(docs);
    }
    asyncCall();
  });
    return (
      <Chart />
        );
    }`
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDFKg.png)

console.log(ref) **Dear  Brettski**

```
t {
  "EP": t {
    "Je": Array [
      t {
        "dir": t {
          "name": "desc",
        },
        "field": e {
          "len": 1,
          "offset": 0,
          "segments": Array [
            "updatedAt",
          ],
        },
        "wn": false,
      },
    ],
    "Ze": "F",
    "collectionGroup": null,
    "en": null,
    "endAt": null,
    "filters": Array [],
    "limit": null,
    "path": e {
      "len": 3,
      "offset": 0,
      "segments": Array [
        "users",
        "undefined",
        "memos",
      ],
    },
    "startAt": null,
    "tn": null,
  },
  "firestore": t {
    "$E": t {
      "tl": [Function anonymous],
    },
    "BE": FirebaseAppImpl {
      "automaticDataCollectionEnabled_": false,
      "container": ComponentContainer {
        "name": "[DEFAULT]",
        "providers": Map {
          "app" => Provider {
            "component": Component {
              "instanceFactory": [Function anonymous],
              "instantiationMode": "LAZY",
              "multipleInstances": false,
              "name": "app",
              "serviceProps": Object {},
              "type": "PUBLIC",
            },
            "container": [Circular],
            "instances": Map {
              "[DEFAULT]" => [Circular],
            },
            "instancesDeferred": Map {},
            "name": "app",
          },
          "platform-logger" => Provider {
            "component": Component {
              "instanceFactory": [Function anonymous],
              "instantiationMode": "LAZY",
              "multipleInstances": false,
              "name": "platform-logger",
              "serviceProps": Object {},
              "type": "PRIVATE",
            },
            "container": [Circular],
            "instances": Map {},
            "instancesDeferred": Map {},
            "name": "platform-logger",
          },
          "fire-core-rn-version" => Provider {
            "component": Component {
              "instanceFactory": [Function anonymous],
              "instantiationMode": "LAZY",
              "multipleInstances": false,
              "name": "fire-core-rn-version",
              "serviceProps": Object {},
              "type": "VERSION",
            },
            "container": [Circular],
            "instances": Map {},
            "instancesDeferred": Map {},
            "name": "fire-core-rn-version",
          },
          "fire-js-version" => Provider {
            "component": Component {
              "instanceFactory": [Function anonymous],
              "instantiationMode": "LAZY",
              "multipleInstances": false,
              "name": "fire-js-version",
              "serviceProps": Object {},
              "type": "VERSION",
            },
            "container": [Circular],
            "instances": Map {},
            "instancesDeferred": Map {},
            "name": "fire-js-version",
          },
          "auth" => Provider {
            "component": Object {
              "instanceFactory": [Function instanceFactory],
              "instantiationMode": "LAZY",
              "multipleInstances": false,
              "name": "auth",
              "serviceProps": Object {
                "ActionCodeInfo": Object {
                  "Operation": Object {
                    "EMAIL_SIGNIN": "EMAIL_SIGNIN",
                    "PASSWORD_RESET": "PASSWORD_RESET",
                    "RECOVER_EMAIL": "RECOVER_EMAIL",
                    "VERIFY_EMAIL": "VERIFY_EMAIL",
                  },
                },
                "ActionCodeURL": [Function d],
                "Auth": [Function Lm],
                "AuthCredential": [Function kg],
                "EmailAuthProvider": [Function d],
                "Error": [Function M],
                "FacebookAuthProvider": [Function d],
                "GithubAuthProvider": [Function d],
                "GoogleAuthProvider": [Function d],
                "OAuthProvider": [Function d],
                "PhoneAuthProvider": [Function d],
                "RecaptchaVerifier": [Function d],
                "SAMLAuthProvider": [Function d],
                "TwitterAuthProvider": [Function d],
              },
              "type": "PUBLIC",
            },
            "container": [Circular],
            "instances": Map {
              "[DEFAULT]" => Object {
                "apiKey": "AIzaSyA0Dg2wLA3WzYe5EEbFHec1YwCDeFwqiUw",
                "appName": "[DEFAULT]",
                "authDomain": "assets-5744f.firebaseapp.com",
                "currentUser": null,
              },
            },
            "instancesDeferred": Map {},
            "name": "auth",
          },
          "auth-internal" => Provider {
            "component": Object {
              "instanceFactory": [Function instanceFactory],
              "instantiationMode": "LAZY",
              "multipleInstances": false,
              "name": "auth-internal",
              "type": "PRIVATE",
            },
            "container": [Circular],
            "instances": Map {
              "[DEFAULT]" => Object {
                "addAuthTokenListener": [Function bound ],
                "getToken": [Function bound ],
                "getUid": [Function bound ],
                "removeAuthTokenListener": [Function bound ],
              },
            },
            "instancesDeferred": Map {},
            "name": "auth-internal",
          },
          "fire-auth-version" => Provider {
            "component": Component {
              "instanceFactory": [Function anonymous],
              "instantiationMode": "LAZY",
              "multipleInstances": false,
              "name": "fire-auth-version",
              "serviceProps": Object {},
              "type": "VERSION",
            },
            "container": [Circular],
            "instances": Map {},
            "instancesDeferred": Map {},
            "name": "fire-auth-version",
          },
          "database" => Provider {
            "component": Component {
              "instanceFactory": [Function anonymous],
              "instantiationMode": "LAZY",
              "multipleInstances": true,
              "name": "database",
              "serviceProps": Object {
                "DataSnapshot": [Function DataSnapshot],
                "Database": [Function Database],
                "INTERNAL": Object {
                  "dataUpdateCount": [Function dataUpdateCount],
                  "forceLongPolling": [Function forceLongPolling],
                  "forceWebSockets": [Function forceWebSockets],
                  "interceptServerData": [Function interceptServerData],
                  "isWebSocketsAvailable": [Function isWebSocketsAvailable],
                  "setSecurityDebugCallback": [Function setSecurityDebugCallback],
                  "stats": [Function stats],
                  "statsIncrementCounter": [Function statsIncrementCounter],
                },
                "Query": [Function Query],
                "Reference": [Function Reference],
                "ServerValue": Object {
                  "TIMESTAMP": Object {
                    ".sv": "timestamp",
                  },
                },
                "TEST_ACCESS": Object {
                  "ConnectionTarget": [Function RepoInfo],
                  "DataConnection": [Function PersistentConnection],
                  "RealTimeConnection": [Function Connection],
                  "forceRestClient": [Function forceRestClient],
                  "hijackHash": [Function hijackHash],
                  "queryIdentifier": [Function queryIdentifier],
                },
                "enableLogging": [Function enableLogging],
              },
              "type": "PUBLIC",
            },
            "container": [Circular],
            "instances": Map {},
            "instancesDeferred": Map {},
            "name": "database",
          },
          "fire-rtdb-version" => Provider {
            "component": Component {
              "instanceFactory": [Function anonymous],
              "instantiationMode": "LAZY",
              "multipleInstances": false,
              "name": "fire-rtdb-version",
              "serviceProps": Object {},
              "type": "VERSION",
            },
            "container": [Circular],
            "instances": Map {},
            "instancesDeferred": Map {},
            "name": "fire-rtdb-version",
          },
          "storage" => Provider {
            "component": Component {
              "instanceFactory": [Function factory],
              "instantiationMode": "LAZY",
              "multipleInstances": true,
              "name": "storage",
              "serviceProps": Object {
                "Reference": [Function Reference],
                "Storage": [Function Service],
                "StringFormat": Object {
                  "BASE64": "base64",
                  "BASE64URL": "base64url",
                  "DATA_URL": "data_url",
                  "RAW": "raw",
                },
                "TaskEvent": Object {
                  "STATE_CHANGED": "state_changed",
                },
                "TaskState": Object {
                  "CANCELED": "canceled",
                  "ERROR": "error",
                  "PAUSED": "paused",
                  "RUNNING": "running",
                  "SUCCESS": "success",
                },
              },
              "type": "PUBLIC",
            },
            "container": [Circular],
            "instances": Map {},
            "instancesDeferred": Map {},
            "name": "storage",
          },
          "fire-gcs-version" => Provider {
            "component": Component {
              "instanceFactory": [Function anonymous],
              "instantiationMode": "LAZY",
              "multipleInstances": false,
              "name": "fire-gcs-version",
              "serviceProps": Object {},
              "type": "VERSION",
            },
            "container": [Circular],
            "instances"...(truncated to the first 10000 characters)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioghq.png)

Actually, I'm not sure this is a sub-collection or not.
Could you identify this is sub-collection or not with this picture?

console.log(snapshot) **Dear Shree Charan**

```
t {
  "SP": null,
  "gP": t {
    "Je": Array [
      t {
        "dir": t {
          "name": "desc",
        },
        "field": e {
          "len": 1,
          "offset": 0,
          "segments": Array [
            "updatedAt",
          ],
        },
        "wn": false,
      },
    ],
    "Ze": "F",
    "collectionGroup": null,
    "en": t {
      "Ye": "users/undefined/memos|f:|ob:updatedAtdesc,__name__desc,",
      "collectionGroup": null,
      "endAt": null,
      "filters": Array [],
      "limit": null,
      "orderBy": Array [
        t {
          "dir": t {
            "name": "desc",
          },
          "field": e {
            "len": 1,
            "offset": 0,
            "segments": Array [
              "updatedAt",
            ],
          },
          "wn": false,
        },
        t {
          "dir": t {
            "name": "desc",
          },
          "field": e {
            "len": 1,
            "offset": 0,
            "segments": Array [
              "__name__",
            ],
          },
          "wn": true,
        },
      ],
      "path": e {
        "len": 3,
        "offset": 0,
        "segments": Array [
          "users",
          "undefined",
          "memos",
        ],
      },
      "startAt": null,
    },
    "endAt": null,
    "filters": Array [],
    "limit": null,
    "path": e {
      "len": 3,
      "offset": 0,
      "segments": Array [
        "users",
        "undefined",
        "memos",
      ],
    },
    "startAt": null,
    "tn": Array [
      t {
        "dir": t {
          "name": "desc",
        },
        "field": e {
          "len": 1,
          "offset": 0,
          "segments": Array [
            "updatedAt",
          ],
        },
        "wn": false,
      },
      t {
        "dir": t {
          "name": "desc",
        },
        "field": e {
          "len": 1,
          "offset": 0,
          "segments": Array [
            "__name__",
          ],
        },
        "wn": true,
      },
    ],
  },
  "iP": undefined,
  "metadata": t {
    "fromCache": false,
    "hasPendingWrites": false,
  },
  "nP": t {
    "$E": t {
      "tl": [Function anonymous],
    },
    "BE": FirebaseAppImpl {
      "automaticDataCollectionEnabled_": false,
      "container": ComponentContainer {
        "name": "[DEFAULT]",
        "providers": Map {
          "app" => Provider {
            "component": Component {
              "instanceFactory": [Function anonymous],
              "instantiationMode": "LAZY",
              "multipleInstances": false,
              "name": "app",
              "serviceProps": Object {},
              "type": "PUBLIC",
            },
            "container": [Circular],
            "instances": Map {
              "[DEFAULT]" => [Circular],
            },
            "instancesDeferred": Map {},
            "name": "app",
          },
          "platform-logger" => Provider {
            "component": Component {
              "instanceFactory": [Function anonymous],
              "instantiationMode": "LAZY",
              "multipleInstances": false,
              "name": "platform-logger",
              "serviceProps": Object {},
              "type": "PRIVATE",
            },
            "container": [Circular],
            "instances": Map {},
            "instancesDeferred": Map {},
            "name": "platform-logger",
          },
          "fire-core-rn-version" => Provider {
            "component": Component {
              "instanceFactory": [Function anonymous],
              "instantiationMode": "LAZY",
              "multipleInstances": false,
              "name": "fire-core-rn-version",
              "serviceProps": Object {},
              "type": "VERSION",
            },
            "container": [Circular],
            "instances": Map {},
            "instancesDeferred": Map {},
            "name": "fire-core-rn-version",
          },
          "fire-js-version" => Provider {
            "component": Component {
              "instanceFactory": [Function anonymous],
              "instantiationMode": "LAZY",
              "multipleInstances": false,
              "name": "fire-js-version",
              "serviceProps": Object {},
              "type": "VERSION",
            },
            "container": [Circular],
            "instances": Map {},
            "instancesDeferred": Map {},
            "name": "fire-js-version",
          },
          "auth" => Provider {
            "component": Object {
              "instanceFactory": [Function instanceFactory],
              "instantiationMode": "LAZY",
              "multipleInstances": false,
              "name": "auth",
              "serviceProps": Object {
                "ActionCodeInfo": Object {
                  "Operation": Object {
                    "EMAIL_SIGNIN": "EMAIL_SIGNIN",
                    "PASSWORD_RESET": "PASSWORD_RESET",
                    "RECOVER_EMAIL": "RECOVER_EMAIL",
                    "VERIFY_EMAIL": "VERIFY_EMAIL",
                  },
                },
                "ActionCodeURL": [Function d],
                "Auth": [Function Lm],
                "AuthCredential": [Function kg],
                "EmailAuthProvider": [Function d],
                "Error": [Function M],
                "FacebookAuthProvider": [Function d],
                "GithubAuthProvider": [Function d],
                "GoogleAuthProvider": [Function d],
                "OAuthProvider": [Function d],
                "PhoneAuthProvider": [Function d],
                "RecaptchaVerifier": [Function d],
                "SAMLAuthProvider": [Function d],
                "TwitterAuthProvider": [Function d],
              },
              "type": "PUBLIC",
            },
            "container": [Circular],
            "instances": Map {
              "[DEFAULT]" => Object {
                "apiKey": "AIzaSyA0Dg2wLA3WzYe5EEbFHec1YwCDeFwqiUw",
                "appName": "[DEFAULT]",
                "authDomain": "assets-5744f.firebaseapp.com",
                "currentUser": Object {
                  "apiKey": "AIzaSyA0Dg2wLA3WzYe5EEbFHec1YwCDeFwqiUw",
                  "appName": "[DEFAULT]",
                  "authDomain": "assets-5744f.firebaseapp.com",
                  "createdAt": "1612675890112",
                  "displayName": null,
                  "email": "user1@example.com",
                  "emailVerified": false,
                  "isAnonymous": false,
                  "lastLoginAt": "1613219679007",
                  "phoneNumber": null,
                  "photoURL": null,
                  "providerData": Array [
                    Object {
                      "displayName": null,
                      "email": "user1@example.com",
                      "phoneNumber": null,
                      "photoURL": null,
                      "providerId": "password",
                      "uid": "user1@example.com",
                    },
                  ],
                  "redirectEventId": null,
                  "stsTokenManager": Object {
                    "accessToken": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjYxMDgzMDRiYWRmNDc1MWIyMWUwNDQwNTQyMDZhNDFkOGZmMWNiYTgiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL3NlY3VyZXRva2VuLmdvb2dsZS5jb20vYXNzZXRzLTU3NDRmIiwiYXVkIjoiYXNzZXRzLTU3NDRmIiwiYXV0aF90aW1lIjoxNjEzMjE5Njc5LCJ1c2VyX2lkIjoiZjZmT0UzQ3hpWlN4ekFiekwxYXdIZ01uZXRJMyIsInN1YiI6ImY2Zk9FM0N4aVpTeHpBYnpMMWF3SGdNbmV0STMiLCJpYXQiOjE2MTMyODc2MDgsImV4cCI6MTYxMzI5MTIwOCwiZW1haWwiOiJ1c2VyMUBleGFtcGxlLmNvbSIsImVtYWlsX3ZlcmlmaWVkIjpmYWxzZSwiZmlyZWJhc2UiOnsiaWRlbnRpdGllcyI6eyJlbWFpbCI6WyJ1c2VyMUBleGFtcGxlLmNvbSJdfSwic2lnbl9pbl9wcm92aWRlciI6InBhc3N3b3JkIn19.U-OXeXG2kXtFAn0WmKHNYk7xTldRIHOrHloVBT41NWP5JVFWhG1I6fjmvNTQO1fBVtfSlL6Vjdohgeu7A1jrAs-WoJewaHQUEq--_3JklJ1p7elrnfqbrOsOBrwf6_41Tw4FPV3qmzlv5w-h2mvhG3qeFgyjR3YYAUn8jeRVgjx4HHvv59KLKUTEUq8NGR3UeGDVvifiwVOVGMmRZ2Ttq91m4F19W4Y-mT4sM-rbMZgd2XW5-W-Knz6wh3QmWWzULlHEA6Fo8uImNJ8tflJ755sBmHFbpJhvA39pjk0kSKWKKEOavI9s7c5zh_Zf94fpbAGu2myxwySp5BaoTbk5bg",
                    "apiKey": "AIzaSyA0Dg2wLA3WzYe5EEbFHec1YwCDeFwqiUw",
                    "expirationTime": 1613291205148,
                    "refreshToken": "AOvuKvRyJkAs06AhzjWZtlFbCqXxbmYKGZnqVNivNPnbWpOFnZQ-83LawZKhmzCsgH7e7Q8hE5QF3J886YMeoc1xf2-bgpppT1HJo2jkCRFYAvDNlMRlWaFm2AUeYlzJuG5iO53iRcwSFKDajlSgZfEy07N_H8fntDEFmuF_jwM0RTxqkQC-l4KaoTCYs6dgXTv00nt8y6uN",
                  },
                  "tenantId": null,
                  "uid": "f6fOE3CxiZSxzAbzL1awHgMnetI3",
                },
              },
            },
            "instancesDeferred": Map {},
            "name": "auth",
          },
          "auth-internal" => Provider {
            "component": Object {
              "instanceFactory": [Function instanceFactory],
              "instantiationMode": "LAZY",
              "multipleInstances": false,
              "name": "auth-internal",
              "type": "PRIVATE",
            },
            "container": [Circular],
            "instances": Map {
              "[DEFAULT]" => Object {
                "addAuthTokenListener": [Function bound ],
                "getToken": [Function bound ],
                "getUid": [Function bound ],
                "removeAuthTokenListener": [Function bound ],
              },
            },
            "instancesDeferred": Map {},
            "name": "auth-internal",
          },
          "fire-auth-version" => Provider {
            "component": Component {
              "instanceFactory": [Function anonymous],
              "instantiationMode": "LAZY",
              "multipleInstances": false,
              "name": "fire-auth-version",
              "serviceProps": Object {},
              "type": "VERSION",
            },
            "container": [Circular],
            "instances": Map {},
            "instancesDeferred": Map {},
            "name": "fire-auth-version",
          },
          "database" => Provider {
            "component": Component {
              "instanceFacto...(truncated to the first 10000 characters)
```

Comment: I thought you were supposed to call `get` before getting the snapshots, also js has `async` and `await` I don't understand why you're using callbacks: `const ref = await db.collection('users/${currentUser.uid}/memos').orderBy('updatedAt', 'desc').get()` then `const docs = ref.docs.map(doc => doc.data()); console.log(docs) `, but this needs to be wrapped in an asynchronous function.

Comment: Would you mind logging data of ```snapshot``` , does it have data or is it empty ?

Comment: @Bargros Thank you for your helping. I am an amateur so I just tried to do that as you said. I've got a parsing error to this part `const docs = ref.docs.map(doc => doc.data()); ` I googled about asynchronous function. But I haven't been finding how I can fix the parsing error. if you an ok, let me know why my cord doesn't work please. I'll put code.

Comment: @LongNguyễnThành Thank you for your helping... I put `console.log(snapshot)`after `unsubscribe = ref.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {`. snapshot's data was displayed so it is not empty!

Comment: Can you check the error log once, you might need to create an index on firestore first.

Comment: @ShreeCharan  Thank you for your helping!   I can't get any error logs. It just shows nothing on the console...    and I guess I have already an index on firebase. I put a screenshot of the firebase index. So please check it out it works the right way.

Comment: My apologies, I am not aware to what `async function asyncCall()` does. You shouldn't need an index on a single value orderBy, those indexes are set for us. Try sending ref to console and see what you get. My guess it that you are not resolving your Promise. There is also a `docs.size` on the object referring to the number of documents returned. In react is `useEffect(async () => {...` valid? Seems that should work for your `await`

Comment: in, `db.collection('users/${currentUser.uid}/memos')` is `memos` a sub-collection? If yes does it exist for the userId being tested with?

Comment: @user43942 can you post what console.log(snapshot) gives you, that will help

Comment: @user43942 snapshot might just be an empty array because there are no docs in the specified collection, hence nothing is logged in the forEach block

Comment: @Brettski Thank you for your help!!!  Actually, I'm not sure this is a sub-collection or not. Could you identify this is sub-collection or not with this picture added above?

Comment: @ShreeCharan Thank you for replying to me. I added a picture of the snapshot's console!  What's wrong with it!?

Comment: We can't tell if ```users/${currentUser.uid}/memos``` points to a subcollection or not. Personally I don't recommend this structure. You might want to have ```/users``` and ```/memos``` collections where memo document has userId field. I think ```db.collection('col/doc/sub')``` is usage. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model
https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/CollectionReference.html

Comment: @Watanabe.N Thank you for your help and some info. I checked both of them but I am not sure how I have collections where memo document has userID field... I'll find how I can do that! I appreciate!

Comment: @user43942 It's very simple. Just make /memos collection, and when you add a document into /memos, put userId field. This article, https://geekyants.com/blog/modelling-twitter-in-cloud-firestore-29, might help.

Comment: I don't recognize that object you posted. Few things to make sure: `currentUser.uid` is actually a document id in your user collection (based on your image), Your query uses `.get()` to actually send the request to Firestore, You await/then the Promise returned from `.get()` so you are working with the query snapshot returned (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#get). The QuerySnapshot returned from `.get()` contains `docs` (array) and `size` (number) I don't write React so I can't explicitly say how to change your code.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
unsubscribe = ref.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  console.log(doc.id, doc.data());
  });
 }, (error) => {
console.log(error);
 });
```

to

```
unsubscribe = ref.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
  console.log(doc.id, doc.data());
  });
 }, (error) => {
console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: I tried this but It doesn't work...   Thank you.